# Javascript preventdefault does work on document but not on selected Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a little code to disable scrolling when you press arrowKeys. If you apply the code to the document it works. Window also works, but if you apply it to the div which should have it disabled or the parent of that div it does not work. Does anyone know a solution?
https://jsfiddle.net/Autumnlight/ypgjd7kx/21/

Html:

```
<div id="ye">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Css:

```
div {
max-width:150px;
height:50px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Js:

```
document.getElementById("ye").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
  if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
    preventDefault(e);
    return false;
  }
}

// modern Chrome requires { passive: false } when adding event
var supportsPassive = false;
try {
  window.addEventListener("test", null, Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
    get: function () { supportsPassive = true; } 
  }));
} catch(e) {}

var wheelOpt = supportsPassive ? { passive: false } : false;
var wheelEvent = 'onwheel' in document.createElement('div') ? 'wheel' : 'mousewheel';

// call this to Disable
function disableScroll() {
  window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false); // older FF
  window.addEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt); // modern desktop
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt); // mobile
  window.addEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}

// call this to Enable
function enableScroll() {
  window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.removeEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt); 
  window.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt);
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}
document.getElementById("ye").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    disableScroll();
});
disableScroll();
```

```css
div {
  max-width:350px;
  height:50px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="ye">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

</div>
```

Comment: Allan, the solution was to add tabindex="-1" on the element, the issue is that you cannot have an keydown event listener on a normal div usually, but if u add that attribute it works